# Some commands in some rooms take me to unintended parts of the code

Tags: python, text-based

I'm currently working on this text based game for a python introduction class. I can't figure out why some parts of the code takes me to another part that I didn't assign. Like I would go east then north, which should take me to 'Hidden Mud Warehouse', but it would take me to the beginning room instead. I know there's a lot of mistakes of inefficient way of coding there, but please just comment on how to fix the main problem for now. Thanks

```
def show_ins():

    print("NEUTRALIZE THE ATAKSUKI!")
    print("Team up with 6 teammates to stop the Ataksuki, or they will kill your dear friend")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West, Exit")
    print("Add teammate: get 'teammate name'")
def main():

    rooms = {
        'Hidden Mud Village Hall': {'South': 'The Clinic', 'West': 'The Flower Shop', 'North': 'The Bookstore',
                                    'East': 'Yoga House'},
        'The Clinic': {'North': 'Hidden Mud Village Hall', 'East': 'Weapons Depot', 'teammate': 'Lady Choyi'},
        'Weapons Depot': {'West': 'The Clinic', 'teammate': 'Ten'},
        'The Flower Shop': {'East': 'Hidden Mud Village Hall', 'teammate': 'Askura'},
        'The Bookstore': {'South': 'Hidden Mud Village Hall', 'East': 'The Gym', 'teammate': 'Akashi'},
        'The Gym': {'West': 'The Bookstore', 'teammate': 'Mighty Dude'},
        'Yoga House': {'West': 'Hidden Mud Village Hall', 'North': 'Hidden Mud Warehouse', 'teammate': 'Neju'},
        'Hidden Mud Warehouse': {'South': 'Yoga House', 'character': 'The Ataksuki'}
    }
    teammates = []
    while True:
        show_ins()
        currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Village Hall'
        command = ''
        while currentroom == 'Hidden Mud Warehouse':
            if teammates != ['Lady Choyi', 'Ten', 'Askura', 'Neju', 'Mighty Dude', 'Akashi']:
                print('You failed. Try again.')
            elif teammates == ['Lady Choyi', 'Ten', 'Askura', 'Neju', 'Mighty Dude', 'Akashi']:
                print('Good job! You saved Garaa!')
        while currentroom == 'Hidden Mud Village Hall':
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('You are currently in', currentroom)
            print('Teammates: {}'.format(teammates))
            command = input('Command:\n')
            if command not in ['go south', 'go South', 'go west', 'go West', 'go north', 'go North', 'go east', 'go East', 'exit','Exit']:
                print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Invalid command!')
            elif command in ['exit', 'Exit']:
                currentroom = 'Exit'
                print('Coward! Come back here!')
                quit()
            elif command in ['go south', 'go South']:
                currentroom = 'The Clinic'
            elif command in ['go west', 'go West']:
                currentroom = 'The Flower Shop'
            elif command in ['go north', 'go North']:
                currentroom = 'The Bookstore'
            elif command in ['go east', 'go East']:
                currentroom = 'Yoga House'
        while currentroom == 'The Clinic':
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('You are currently in', currentroom)
            print('You see Lady Choyi')
            print('Teammates: {}'.format(teammates))
            command = input('Command:\n')
            if command not in ['go north', 'go North', 'go east', 'go East', 'exit', 'Exit', 'get lady choyi', 'get Lady Choyi']:
                print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Invalid command!')
            elif command in ['exit', 'Exit']:
                currentroom = 'Exit'
                print('Coward! Come back here!')
                quit()
            elif command in ['get lady choyi', 'get Lady Choyi']:
                print('Lady Choyi has joined you')
                teammates.append ('Lady Choyi')
            elif command in ['go north', 'go North']:
                currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Village Hall'
            elif command in ['go east', 'go East']:
                currentroom = 'Weapons Depot'
        while currentroom == 'The Flower Shop':
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('You are currently in', currentroom)
            print('You see Askura')
            print('Teammates: {}'.format(teammates))
            command = input('Command:\n')
            if command not in ['go east', 'go East', 'exit', 'Exit', 'get askura', 'get Askura']:
                print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Invalid command!')
            elif command in ['exit', 'Exit']:
                currentroom = 'Exit'
                print('Coward! Come back here!')
                quit()
            elif command in ['get askura', 'get Askura']:
                print('Askura has joined you')
                teammates.append ('Askura')
            elif command in ['go east', 'go East']:
                currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Village Hall'
        while currentroom == 'The Bookstore':
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('You are currently in', currentroom)
            print('You see Akashi')
            print('Teammates: {}'.format(teammates))
            command = input('Command:\n')
            if command not in ['go south', 'go South', 'go east', 'go East', 'get akashi', 'get Akashi']:
                print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Invalid command!')
            elif command in ['exit', 'Exit']:
                currentroom = 'Exit'
                print('Coward! Come back here!')
                quit()
            elif command in ['get akashi', 'get Akashi']:
                print('Akashi has joined you')
                teammates.append ('Akashi')
            elif command in ['go south', 'go South']:
                currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Village Hall'
            elif command in ['go east', 'go East']:
                currentroom = 'The Gym'
        while currentroom == 'Yoga House':
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('You are currently in', currentroom)
            print('You see Neju')
            print('Teammates: {}'.format(teammates))
            command = input('Command:\n')
            if command not in ['go west', 'go West', 'go north', 'go North', 'get Neju', 'get neju']:
                print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Invalid command!')
            elif command in ['exit', 'Exit']:
                currentroom = 'Exit'
                print('Coward! Come back here!')
                quit()
            elif command in ['get Neju', 'get neju']:
                print('Neju has joined you')
                teammates.append ('Neju')
            elif command in ['go west', 'go West']:
                currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Village Hall'
            elif command in ['go north', 'go North']:
                currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Warehouse'
        while currentroom == 'Weapons Depot':
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('You are currently in', currentroom)
            print('You see Ten')
            print('Teammates: {}'.format(teammates))
            command = input('Command:\n')
            if command not in ['go west', 'go West', 'exit', 'Exit', 'get ten', 'get Ten']:
                print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Invalid command!')
            elif command in ['exit', 'Exit']:
                currentroom = 'Exit'
                print('Coward! Come back here!')
                quit()
            elif command in ['get ten', 'get Ten']:
                print('Ten has joined you')
                teammates.append ('Ten')
            elif command in ['go west', 'go West']:
                currentroom = 'The Clinic'
        while currentroom == 'The Gym':
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('You are currently in', currentroom)
            print('You see Mighty Dude')
            print('Teammates: {}'.format(teammates))
            command = input('Command:\n')
            if command not in ['go west', 'go West', 'exit', 'Exit', 'get mighty dude', 'get Mighty Dude']:
                print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Invalid command!')
            elif command in ['exit', 'Exit']:
                currentroom = 'Exit'
                print('Coward! Come back here!')
                quit()
            elif command in ['get mighty dude', 'get Mighty Dude']:
                print('Mighty Dude has joined you')
                teammates.append ('Mighty Dude')
            elif command in ['go west', 'go West']:
                currentroom = 'The Bookstore'
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem you're hitting is that your `while` loop resets the current room at the beginning of each iteration:

```
    while True:
        show_ins()
        currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Village Hall'
        ...
```

What you probably want to do instead is set it *before* the loop, and allow the body of the loop to change `currentroom` in response to commands:

```
    currentroom = 'Hidden Mud Village Hall'
    while True:
        show_ins()
        ...
```

Re: *I know there's a lot of mistakes of inefficient way of coding* -- here's an unsolicited suggestion on how you could write code that lets you get from *any* room to any other room using only the information in the `rooms` dictionary (i.e. without needing to have a separate "if currentroom = 'room'" for each room):

```
command = input('Command:\n').lower()
if command[:3] == "go ":
    # this handles *any* "go" command in *any* room using the rooms dict
    d = command[3:]
    if d not in ["north", "south", "east", "west"]:
        print("Invalid direction!")
    elif d not in rooms[currentroom]:
        print(f"Can't go {d} from {currentroom}.")
    else:
        currentroom = rooms[currentroom][d]
    continue
# handle other commands
```

Comment: Also the `elif` should simply be `else`; there is no way for the condition to be false if the opposite `if` condition was.

Comment: ... Though the condition checks for a particular _sequence_ where you would probably simply want to check if it has the same members, in any sequence; a common way to do that is to use a `set` instead of a `list`, or convert the `list` to a `set` and then compare.

Comment: Furthermore, the code uses `while` in several places where clearly you mean `if`, or else the code within the loop should change the current room so that the `while` condition becomes untrue; otherwise, you have an endless loop.